# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - still adds to API though after page reload?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, es6-class

I am trying to use a form to create a basic card. After entering the data from the form it should create the "card" and render the data immediately. However, 2 things:

1. It only renders it after reloading the page
2. It throws the error in the title:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

This is the event listener for the form.

```
const api = new API()
const form = document.getElementById("newDrinkForm")

form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const name = event.target.name.value
    const caffeine = event.target.caffeine.value

    const ul = document.querySelector("ul")

    api.addDrink(name, caffeine)
    .then(drink => {
        name.value = ""
        caffeine.value = ""
        const newDrink = new Drink(drink)
        ul.append(newDrink)
        console.log(newDrink)
    })
})
```

This is the Drink class

```
class Drink {

    constructor(data) {
        // Assign Attributes //
        this.id = data.id
        this.name = data.name
        this.caffeine = data.caffeine

        // Build Comment Dependents //
        const comments = data.comments.map(comment => new Comment(comment, this))

        // Build Associated Drink Card //
        this.card = new DrinkCard(this, comments)
    }
    
    delete = () => {
        api.deleteDrink(this.id)
        delete this
    }
}
```

addDrink function:

```
addDrink(name, caffeine) {
    const drink = {
      name: name,
      caffeine: caffeine,
    }

    return fetch(this.drinkURL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: this.headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(drink)
      }).then(this.parseJSON)
      .catch(this.catchError)
  }
```

JSON of drinks

```
[
  {
   id: 26,
   name: "Coffee",
   caffeine: "80mg",
   comments: [
     {
       id: 8,
       summary: "test",
       drink_id: 26,
       created_at: "2021-02-02T02:13:15.190Z",
       updated_at: "2021-02-02T02:13:15.190Z"
     }
   ]
  }
]
```

I know it's receiving the error here:

```
const comments = data.comments.map(comment => new Comment(comment, this))
```

Any ideas to help me sort out what the issue is? Is it because it's trying to create an empty array so it can map it to the `new Comment`? If so, ideas to work around the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`comments` is `undefined` in the response object `drinks`, do a `console.log(drinks)` to verify that and check the `api.addDrink` method for why.

Comment: Added addDrink and the JSON of the entry. So, it's probably because I am not handling those comments in the addDrink. How can I include the Comments object inside of that?